# Ordering problem when using Ruby popen2 to interact with C++ iostreams

Tags: ruby, iostream, popen

I'm using Open3's popen2 to interact with a simple C++ program's iostreams.  My understanding is that std::cin and std::cout are independent, but the order in which I have my popen2 block's IO objects read/write calls seems to make a difference.  My C++ program is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string input;
  std::cout<<"EXECUTE TASK"<<std::endl;
  std::cin>>input;
  std::cout<<"END"<<std::endl;
}
```

My ruby script is:

```
require 'open3'
expected_string = "EXECUTE TASK"
Open3.popen2('~/Sandbox/a.out') { |stdin, stdout|
  stdin.write('\n')
  stdin.close
  results = stdout.readlines
  puts results
}
```

The above works fine, but if I move the `stdout.readlines` before the `stdin.close`, the ruby script will hang.  My intent is to conditionally write the \n to stdin if the C++ program writes `expected_string` to standard out first, but I'm forced to close the stdin stream before I can execute readlines.  Like I said, my understanding was that the two streams are independent, and the file descriptors returned by popen2 appear to be independent as well, so why would the order matter?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Solution with full scope of what I was trying to accomplish (someone may find this helpful):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string input;

    std::cout<<"1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"2"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"3"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"4"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"5"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"EXECUTE TASK"<<std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
    std::cin>>input;
    std::cout<<"END"<<std::endl;
}


require 'open3'

expected_string = "EXECUTE TASK"
Open3.popen2('~/Sandbox/a.out') { |stdin, stdout|
  found = false
  begin
    while(result = stdout.readline)
      puts result
      if(result.include?(expected_string))
        found = true
        break
      end
    end
  rescue
    raise "Exception caught while reading lines"
  end
  stdin.write('\n')
  stdin.close
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a deadlock:

1. The ruby script is calling `IO::readlines`, which will not return until the entire stream has been read.
2. The C++ program does not actually terminate until it receives a carriage return.

You may want to call `IO::readline`, which will return each line as it is received, or reorder the two scripts so that there is not a deadlock.

Comment: That worked.  Will edit the solution in original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that you just need `stdout.flush` after anything that you expect your correspondent to act on.

Because the pipe set up by `#popen` is not a tty, it will not default to line buffering. It will do block buffering. You will need to force your stream to act in datagram fashion by calling `#flush` on "record" boundaries.

Also, see [`IO#sync=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/IO.html#M000576) for a way to flush all I/O automatically.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I had already tried flushing before using both the stdout and stdin IO objects and it still exhibits the same behavior.  Also worth mentioning is that if my C++ program only uses one of the streams rather than both cin and cout, the ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: Both the C++ and the Ruby ends of the stream probably need flush operations.

Comment: So I added `std::cout.flush();` to the C++ after my cout, and a stdout.flush after the stdout.readlines and still no dice.  I'll post the code above.